# Why does my angular resource ignore the action-specific url?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have the following angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Post', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/post', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', url: '/post/get/:id', params: { id: '@id' } },
        save: { method: 'POST', url: '/post/addorupdate/:id', params: { id: '@id' } },
        delete: { method: 'POST', url: '/post/delete/:id', params: { id: '@id' } }
    });
});

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, Post) {
    $scope.createPost = function () {
        var post = new Post({
            title: "Test post",
            body: "Test body.<br/ >Yay!"
        });
        post.$save();
    };
});
```

The markup looks like this:

```
<body data-ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller="appController">
        <button ng-click="createPost()">Create Post</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click the button it tries to do a POST to the server, but to the original URL and not the action-specific URL. The URL from the request looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/post?id=undefined
```

Any idea why it's trying to POST to just `/post`? Also, any idea why `id=undefined`? In other examples it seems like `?id=blah` just isn't included in the request if the ID isn't specified. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.8/src/ngResource/resource.js#L441) in the [current version (1.0.8) of AngularJS](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js) as of this writing. `ngResource` is ignoring the `url` property on action overrides. [It was fixed in version 1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.4/src/ngResource/resource.js#L443) and the fix is present in the latest [release candidate (1.2.0)](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js).

Comment: This bug also seems to be present in Angular 1.2.3

Comment: @ac360 ngResource is a separate file. Are you sure you have the right version of ngResource? Because [it does appear to be checking `action.url` in 1.2.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.3/src/ngResource/resource.js#L457) like it's supposed to. I upgraded Angular once and forgot to upgrade that file.